# Epochs and batches control in Keras

Tags: python, keras, training-data

I would like to implement an autoencoder model that acts as following:

```
for epoch in xrange(100):
  for X_batch in batch_list:
     model.train_on_batch(X_batch, X_batch)
     training_error = model.evaluate(X_batch, X_batch, verbose=0)
  "average the training error by the number of the batches considered"
  "save it as the epoch training error"
  "call the function to get the validation error in the same fashion over  the validation data"
  "compare the two errors and decide whether go on training or stopping"
```

By looking around `fit_generator` seemed an option but I did not understand how to use it.
Should I instead use the `train_on_batch` or the `fit` with just one epoch to properly fit the model?

Which is the best practice for such case?

Comment: Can you explain the first paragraph again? Do you mean that you you want to stop or continue training on the basis of validation error? Something like early stopping?

Comment: I have updated with your suggestions, thank you. Yes exactly. But my problem is actually before: is it correct to use train_on_batch? Or should I use fit? Or fit.generator? I do not find any exhaustive example on Internet and I am doing by chance.

Comment: I have just written as a pseudo code, I have still not implemented, I am wondering about what should I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, you want to use validation error as early stopping criteria. Good news is that keras already has early stopping callback. SO all you need is to create a callback and call it during training after some epochs/iterations.

```
keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=0, verbose=0, mode='auto', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False)
```

Let us look at train_on_batch and fit()

```
train_on_batch(x, y, sample_weight=None, class_weight=None)


fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None)
```

You can see that train_on_batch doesn't take any callback as input, so good choice is to use fit here, unless you want to implement it by yourself.

Now you can call fit as following

```
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2),
         ModelCheckpoint(filepath='path to latest ckpt', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]

history = model.fit(train_features,train_target, epochs=num_epochs, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=0, batch_size=your_choice, validation_data)
```